# Purple rash on Espelette Pepper leaves

Tags: plant-health, peppers, chili

This is my first time posting on this stack, so excuse any ignorance! I have been growing Espelette Peppers in Paris (France) under a grow light during the colder days and hardening them off to our sun-baked south facing terrace. It’s been slow growing, but one plant did particularly well under my inexperienced guidance. However, it now has a sort of purple rash on it’s leaves. I’ve googled and googled and googled, but so far nothing.

Anyone have an idea of what I’m looking at? Or how I might treat it?

Thanks guys!

[image: Espelette Chilli Leaf]
[image: Espelette Chilli Leaf]
[image: Espelette Chilli Plant]

Answer (score 1):

It's probably phosphorus deficiency exacerbated by the cold. Just give it some [monoammonium phosphate](https://www.greenwaybiotech.com/products/monoammonium-phosphate-12-61-0-100-water-soluble), or [monopotassium phosphate](https://www.greenwaybiotech.com/products/monopotassium-phosphate); or else fertilize it generally (make sure your fertilizer has enough phosphorus) and warm up your plant, and the new growth should clear up.

Cold weather can make plants require more phosphorus; it can make phosphorus less available, too. Phosphorus deficiency often results in purple on the leaves. Phosphorus is important for cold-tolerance.